# Elasticsearch get by id doesn't work but document exists

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm seeing weird behaviours with ids on elasticsearch 1.2.0 (recently upgraded from 1.0.1).

A search retrieves my document, showing the correct value for _id:

[terminal]

```
curl 'myServer:9200/global/_search?q=someField:something
```

result is

```
{
  "took": 79,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 12,
    "successful": 12,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 17.715034,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "global",
        "_type": "user",
        "_id": "7a113e4f-44de-3b2b-a3f1-fb881da1b00a",
        ...
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But a direct lookup on id doesn't:
[terminal]

```
curl 'myServer:9200/global/user/7a113e4f-44de-3b2b-a3f1-fb881da1b00a'
```

result is

```
{
  "_index": "global",
  "_type": "user",
  "_id": "7a113e4f-44de-3b2b-a3f1-fb881da1b00a",
  "found": false
}
```

It seems that this is on documents that have previously been updated using custom scripting.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should upgrade to 1.2.1 
Due to release notes (http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/elasticsearch-1-2-1-released/) there are some problems, especially with get:

`There was a routing bug in Elasticsearch 1.2.0 that could have a number of bad side effects on the cluster. Possible side effects include:

documents that were indexed prior to the upgrade to 1.2.0 may not be accessible via get. A search would find these documents, but not a direct get of the document by ID.`

Comment: The tool is here by the way: http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/tool-help-routing-issues-elasticsearch-1-2-0/