# Using URL as ID in ElasticSearch

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I'm using ElasticSearch 6.2.3 and I'm indexing documents with IDs being URLs. When I query the index:

```
GET /ecm_sync/_search
{
  "query": {"match_all": {}}
}
```

I get:

```
...
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "ecm_sync",
        "_type": "doc",
        "_id": "workspace://SpacesStore/07dfa82d-c6ce-469d-b881-4fab6cd9a277",
        "_score": 1,
...
```

Now, if I take this URL and try to GET it directly:

```
GET /ecm_sync/_doc/workspace%3A%2F%2FSpacesStore%2F07dfa82d-c6ce-469d-b881-4fab6cd9a277
```

I get:

```
{
  "_index": "ecm_sync",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "workspace://SpacesStore/07dfa82d-c6ce-469d-b881-4fab6cd9a277",
  "found": false
}
```

The same thing happens both with Kibana and curl. I've seen there was an opened issue long time ago but it was closed so I don't know if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: have you tried an ID that doesn't include special characters? Just the UUID part? Does that happen to work?

Comment: Yes and it doesn't work. I'm aware of ES tokenizing fields by special characters so I wasn't sure if it does the same for IDs.

Comment: Take a look at this question / answer, related to routing with non-default IDs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21003370/elasticsearch-returns-document-in-search-but-not-in-get ... I'm not offering it as an answer as it is old, but maybe there is something in there you can use. In the past I had to specify a mapping to prevent tokenization. That may not be the case any longer.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand the routing. I've never set it directly. Is there any way to list all routings?

Comment: Possibly, but I haven't used elasticsearch in a while, so I'd need to search for it.

Answer (score 3):

Such `_id` format (with *special/reserved* characters) will likely come to warning/error when used in *"query-string search"*. Use *request body search*:

```
GET ecm_sync/doc/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "_id": {
        "value": "workspace://SpacesStore/07dfa82d-c6ce-469d-b881-4fab6cd9a277"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

If you still need to search for some tricky string via query string search (though unwanted) you have to escape all *reserved* characters manually:

```
GET ecm_sync/doc/_search?q=_id:workspace\:\/\/SpacesStore\/07dfa82d\-c6ce\-469d\-b881\-4fab6cd9a277
```

> The reserved characters are: `+ - = && || > < ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? : \ /`

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html

Comment: This works, thanks, but I guess there has to be a correct way to refer to document by ID (so I'll wait a bit before accepting your answer).

Comment: @Bade, see my update. But you should prefer "request body search" in such cases

Comment: Yes, this works too. Too bad I can't escape it the same way in ID part of a _doc GET